# TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable python when i use .join

Tags: python

My objective is to write in the "zerty.txt" file the entries in the list     with several parameters entered when I run file, so I tried many unsuccessful ways

I have read through the many answers to this Error message on SO, none of them have helped me grasp what I am missing.

[imgur.com/Gq1HtXb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9WZB.jpg)
**note_code.py:**

```
import etudiant as MP

liste = []

n = int(input("Nb de d'etudiant : "))

for i in range(0,n):
     a = MP.etudiant()
     a.saisie()
     liste.append(a)

print("les étudiants :")
for p in liste:
    print("-------")
    p.affichage()
    p.save()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4B7i.jpg**etudiant.py:**

```
class etudiant:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nom = "vide"
        self.age = 0

    def saisie(self):
        self.nom = input("Nom : ")
        self.note = int(input("note : "))

    def affichage(self):
        print("Son nom est ", self.nom)
        print("sa note : ", self.note)

    def save(liste):
        with open('zerty.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
            myfile.write('\n'.join(liste))
            myfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Hint: `p.save()`... What does this call? You only have `def save(liste):`

Comment: nrmaly it call the function def save(liste):

Comment: `liste` is an alias to what should be `self`. Are you trying to pass a list there?

Comment: These are two different modules with different global namespaces. The liste you use for the join is in etudiant.py

Comment: always put in question full error message (Traceback) There are other usefull information - ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: use `print(liste, type(liste))` before `join()` to see what you really have.

Comment: yes for me it would take the content of 'liste' (list content different elements from

Comment: 'Nb de d'etudiant : 1'

'Nom : sd'

'note : 2'
'les étudiants :'
'-------'
'Son nom est  sd'
'sa note :  2
<etudiant.etudiant object at 0x000000000907C9B0> <class'''etudiant.etudiant'>
'that the result without .join

Comment: Like I was saying `<class '''etudiant.etudiant'>'` is the otherwise named `self` object, not the `liste` variable that you've defined and appended to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like cricket_007 said you are iterating `liste` in note_code.py but `p` that you get in each loop is an `etudiant` object not a list.

I think what you want to do is something like:

**etudiant.py**

```
class etudiant:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nom = "vide"
        self.age = 0

    def saisie(self):
        self.nom = input("Nom : ")
        self.note = int(input("note : "))

    def affichage(self):
        print("Son nom est ", self.nom)
        print("sa note : ", self.note)

    def save(self):
        with open('zerty.txt', mode='at', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
            myfile.write('\n'.join([self.nom, self.note]))
            myfile.write('\n')
```

But what would be better is:

**note_code.py:**

```
import etudiant as MP

liste = []

n = int(input("Nombre d'étudiants : "))

liste = [MP.etudiant().saisie() for i in range(n)]

print("les étudiants :")
with open('zerty.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for p in liste:
        print("-------")
        p.affichage()
        p.save(myfile)
```

**etudiant.py:**

```
class etudiant:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nom = "vide"
        self.age = 0

    def saisie(self):
        self.nom = input("Nom : ")
        self.note = int(input("note : "))

    def affichage(self):
        print("Son nom est ", self.nom)
        print("sa note : ", self.note)

    def save(self, file_to_save):
        file_to_save.write('{}\n{}\n'.format(self.nom, self.note))
```

J'espère que ça vous aura aidé ;-)

Comment: Merci It helped me ;)

Comment: Would you consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your object is not iterable.

```
def save(liste):
    ...
    myfile.write('\n'.join(liste))  # liste is 'self'
```

Maybe you meant this?

```
def save(self, liste):
```

But, even then, you need a parameter.

```
for p in liste:
    print("-------")
    p.affichage()
    p.save()  # here... save what? 'p.save(liste)', maybe?
```

And note: you can only join a list of strings anyway, so you'd need some additional functionality to convert your objects into a string

Comment: i have a 
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, etudiant found

Comment: Sure. Because you have a list of objects, not strings. You can only join a list of strings